# Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n = [G : e]$, and let $p$ be a prime number such that $p \mid n$ and $p^2 > n$. (cont.)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Can someone help me with this group theory proof? I've given it a bit of a go, but I'm a little stuck. If you could lead me in the right direction without giving it away, that'd be great. The question goes like this:

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n = [G : e]$, and let $p$ be a prime number such that $p \mid n$ and $p^2 > n$. Show that a subgroup of order $p$ is the only subgroup of G with order $p$.

Firstly, what does an order of $[G : e]$ mean? I would think the order of a group would always be $[G : e]$ because that gives the number of cosets with the identity. How might I go about starting this proof?

Comment: The phrasing is odd. "Show that a subgroup of order $p$ is the only subgroup of $G$". Surely that is supposed to be "the only subgroup *of order $p$* of $G$"? Otherwise, a counterexample is $G=S_3$, $p=3$, $n=6$. Also, you never say who $n$ is, so presumably it's supposed be "of order $n=[G:e]$"?

Comment: I phrased it incorrectly, @ArturoMagidin. I will edit the question. We are supposed to show that there is only one subgroup of order p.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Should we use the fact that the intersection of subgroups is a subgroup? And use $P_1 \cap P_2 \leq P1$ followed by Lagrange's Theorem?

Comment: I'm thinking $|P_1 \cap P_2|$ must be the identity, or it must be equal to $P_1$ and $P_2$ because it has to divide $|P_1|$ and $|P_2|$, which is $p$.  Why can't $P_1 \cap P_2 = \{ e \}$?

Comment: In fact, it *must* be $\{e\}$ if $P_1\neq P_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that there are two subgroups of order $p$: $K, H$. Then $K\cap H=\{1\}$. Then the set $HK$ is inside $G$. By the product formula $$|HK|=|K||H|/|K\cap H|=p^2>|G|$$

a contradiction.

Comment: This helps. Thank you. I had forgotten about the product formula.

Answer (score 0):

$|G:1|$ means $|G|$, the order of $G$.

If $p^2>|G|$ then the Sylow $p$-subgroup has order $p$ and its index is $<p$. By the Sylow theorem then the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups must be $\equiv 1 \mod p$ and divide the index. So it is $1$ and there is only one (Sylow) subgroup of order $p$.

Comment: Our book has not introduced the Sylow theorems yet, so I would prefer not to use those. I have started by assuming there are two subgroups of order $p$, $P_1$ and $P_2$. $|P_1 \cap P_2| = 1$ or $p$ by Lagrange's Theorem, but why can't it be the identity? Can we show there is a non-identity element in both $P_1$ and $P_2$, making $|P_1 \cap P_2| \neq \{ e \}$?

Comment: Cauchy's theorem has been introduced. And you are right, I should say which theorems have and haven't been introduced. Doesn't cauchy's theorem just imply there exists a subgroup of order $p$, not that it is unique?

Comment: Cauchy's theorem is proved in a later section on group actions (I believe that is next.) It is just stated in the question, but has not been proven yet. The question states "Assume $G$ has a subgroup of order $p$ (This is always true by Cauchy's Theorem, but treat it as an assumption for the exercise.)"

Comment: Have you studied the class formula? BTW,  the intersection of two different subgroups of order $p$ is always $1$.

Comment: Do you know the product formula?

Comment: I have not studied the class formula. I was trying to use the fact you just said to come to a contradiction. I assumed there are two distinct subgroups of order $p$, namely $P_1$ and $P_2$. Can we show $P_1 \cap P_2 \neq \{ e \}$ to come to the conclusion that they must be the same? Because if they weren't the same, then the intersection must have order 1. In other words, $|P_1 \cap P_2| = p$

Comment: I added another answer.